# Having trouble determining the sample space for conditional expectation problems

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, expected-value

My book states the following theorem

> Let $X$ be a random variable with sample space  $\Omega$. If $F_1, F_2, . . . , F_r$
>   are events such that $F_i$ and $F_j $ are disjoint (for $i$ not equal to $j$) and $\Omega = \cup_jF_j$ then $E(X) = \sum_jE(X|F_j)P(F_j)$

I understand this to mean that given $X$ which can take on a value / outcome from $\Omega$ and $F_1, F_2, . . . , F_r$ are all pairwise disjoint whose union forms $\Omega$, $E(X)$ can be computed by the given equation. However, I had trouble understanding the example illustrating this theorem:

> Let T be the number of rolls in a single play of craps. We can think of a single play as a two-stage process. The first stage consists of a single roll of a pair of dice. The play is over if this roll is a 2, 3, 7,
>   11, or 12. Otherwise, the player's point is established, and the second stage begins. This second stage consists of a sequence of rolls which ends when either the player's point or a 7 is rolled. We record the outcomes of this two-stage experiment using the random variables X and S, where X denotes the first roll, and S denotes the number of rolls in the second stage of the experiment (of course, S is sometimes equal to 0). Note that T = S + 1. Then $E(T) = \sum_{j=2}^{12} E(T|X = j)P(X=j)$

Here I think T is analogous to the X in the theorem above and each outcome of a roll of the two dices ($X = j$) is an event analogous to an $F_j$. However, the potential values of T can take on are in the set $\{1, 2, ... \infty\}$ while I think the set formed by the union of events $X = j$ for all $j$ is just $\{2,3..,12\}$. I'm confused about what the sample space $\Omega$ would be in this example since it appears the values of the random variable and event appear to be drawn from different sets.

Comment: This is called the "law of total expectation" and is very similar to the "law of total probablity."  Indeed their partition is $$ \Omega = \{X=2\}\cup \{X=3\}\cup ...\cup \{X=12\}$$ Every element of the sample space $\Omega$ has the form $$(\mbox{first roll}, \mbox{other rolls}) = (X, \mbox{other rolls})$$ and so the event $\{X=2\}$ is the set of all such elements of the form $(2, \mbox{other rolls})$. Intuitively we know that $X$ can only take values in $\{2, 3, ..., 12\}$ and so the cases $\{X=2\}, \{X=3\}, ..., \{X=12\}$ are mutually exclusive but collectively exhaustive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the "law of total expectation" and is similar to the "law of total probability."  The sample space $\Omega$ is the set of all outcomes $\omega$ of the form: 
$$ \omega = (\mbox{first roll}, \mbox{sequence of other rolls})=(X, \mbox{sequence of other rolls})$$
This sample space can be partitioned into events where the first roll is 2, the first roll is 3, ..., the first roll is 12.  So the partition is: 
$$ \Omega = \{X=2\} \cup \{X=3\}\cup\{X=4\}\cup...\cup\{X=12\}$$
We know that $X$ can only take values in the set $\{2, ..., 12\}$ and so the events $\{X=2\}, \{X=3\}, ..., \{X=12\}$ are indeed mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive.  The event $\{X=4\}$ contains all outcomes that start with a first roll of 4.

---

The individual events $\{X=i\}$ look like this: 
\begin{align}
\{X=2\} &= \{(2)\}\\
\{X=3\} &= \{(3)\}\\
\{X=4\} &= \{(4, 4), (4, 2, 2, 5, 4), (4, 12, 5, 5, 7), (4, 8, 4), ...\}
\end{align}
and so on.  The event $\{X=4\}$ has a countably infinite number of outcomes, but all of them are sequences that start with $4$ and end with either 4 or 7.

The events $\{X=2\}, \{X=3\}, \{X=7\}, \{X=11\}, \{X=12\}$ all contain just one outcome each and so we trivially have
\begin{align}
E[T|X=2]&=1\\
E[T|X=3]&=1\\
E[T|X=7]&=1\\
E[T|X=11]&=1\\
E[T|X=12]&=1
\end{align}
On the other hand, $E[T|X=4]$ is equal to 1 plus the expected time to roll either a 4 or a 7.

Comment: My confusion is the values $T$ can take, because in the example $T$ is specified as number of rolls, so I thought it would take on values $\{1,2,...\infty\}$ and it wasn't obvious to me how that is an outcome in the set $\{X=2\} \cup \{X=3\}\cup\{X=4\}\cup...\cup\{X=12\}$

Comment: Both T and X are random variables, meaning they can be determined by the outcome $\omega$. $$\omega=(4,5,6,5,11,2,4)\implies X(\omega)=4,T(\omega)=7$$ Can you tell me $X(\omega)$ and $T(\omega)$ if $\omega=(8,9,9,7)$?

Comment: Next, can you specify two different outcomes $\omega$ and $v$ such that $X(\omega)\neq X(v)$ but $T(\omega)=T(v)$?

Comment: Following this logic, $X((8,9,9,7)) = 8$ and $T((8,9,9,7)) = 4$. $\omega = (4,9,9,7)$ and $v = (8,9,9,7)$ should satisfy the second problem.

Comment: My book defines random variables as "value of the outcome of a certain experiment" and sample space as "the set of all possible values of [the random variable], or equivalently, the set of all possible outcomes of the experiment". I interpreted this to mean that the random variable must take on a value $\omega \in \Omega$ (kind of like domain of a function), but that's not the case here. $X$ and $T$ both take on values that are not technically an outcome found in $\Omega$. Where is my misunderstanding?

Comment: The yellow excerpts of your book seem fine, but your above quote is not rigorous, either the book is trying to "dumb-down" the definition or it is not an exact quote. If your book had set theory in the beginning it likely described sample spaces $\Omega$ that can be composed of different types of objects such as $\Omega=\{blue, red,green\}$ (the objects are not necessarily numbers).  Elements of the sample space are called _outcomes_, sets of particular outcomes are called _events_. A random variable $X:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function that maps an _outcome_  to a real number.

Comment: With this terminology, the _event_ $\{X=5\}$ is the set of all outcomes $\omega \in \Omega$ for which $X(\omega)=5$. In the dice game, this event has an infinite number of outcomes: $\{X=5\} = \{(5, 5), (5, 1, 2, 1, 5), (5, 6, 4, 7), ...\}$.

Comment: The parts in quotation is from Definition 1.1 and 1.2 on [this pdf, page 26-27](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~prob/prob/prob.pdf). The book consistently describes random variables as an outcome of an experiment and sample space the set of all possible outcomes (so $X$ can be an object like $HH$). The book does have examples where random variables are functions but has never explicitly defined random variables as a function. From what I see, your explanation of random variable appears to be more general and is inclusive of my book's definition?

Comment: Egad!  I don't know how they can get away with this. A _random variable_ $X$ always represents a real number (it is not any other kind of object, certainly not "TT").  That is why every random variable has a _cumulative distribution function_ $F_X(x) = P[X\leq x]$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. The event $\{X\leq x\} = \{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega)\leq x\}$ only makes sense if $X(\omega)$ is a real number, as the inequality $TT\leq x$ makes no sense.  People do use the term "random element" which may be closer to waht your book means. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable

Comment: But even a "random element" never represents the outcome, it is always a _function of the outcome_.  That allows you to work with several different random elements that are all meaningful for the same problem.  In your case, we can work with two different random variables $T$ and $X$, both are functions of the specific outcome $\omega$.

Comment: The book also defines the distribution function of a random variable as $m(\omega)$ where $\omega \in \Omega$. Based on the wiki definition, should the domain of the distribution function be the (real) values the random variable can take on? So for $T$ (in my example), the domain of its distribution function should be $\{1,2,..\infty\}$, not $\Omega$?

Comment: For the discrete case usually people talk of a "probability mass function" $P[T=i]$ for $i \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$, the "cumulative distribution function" $P[T \leq x]$ can be obtained from this and is a staircase function with jumps at positive integers. If the sample space $\Omega$ itself is finite or countably infinite then you can just talk about the probabilities assocaited with each outcome $P[\{\omega\}]$, so $\sum_{\omega \in \Omega} P[\{\omega\}]=1$.